# How to add 'testListener' to custom test reporter in SBT

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

I'm having difficulty implementing a [custom test reporter in Scala using SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Custom+Test+Reporters).

I have a basic SBT project set up with this `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "Test Framework"

version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
scalacOptions += "-feature"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.4" % "test"


testFrameworks += new TestFramework("custom.framework.MyTest")
testListeners += new MyTest()
```

My `MyTest.scala` class is located in the `projects`folder under `projects/custom/framework/MyTest.scala` and looks like this:

```
import sbt.TestsListener._
import sbt.TestReportListener._

class MyTest extends TestReportListener {

    def doInit(): Unit = {
        println("Starting Test")
    }

    def testEvent(event: TestEvent): Unit = {
        println(event.result.get)
    }

    def startGroup(name: String): Unit = {
        println("Group Started")
    }
}
```

The documentation here is sparse, and i'm obviously missing something. It states that i need to

> Specify the test reporters you want to use by overriding the testListeners setting in your project definition. Where customTestListener is of type sbt.TestReportListener.

This should be possible by doing `testListeners += customTestListener`.
Since my `class MyTest extends TestReportListener` i thought i could just do `testListeners += custom.framework.MyTest` or `testListeners += new custom.framework.MyTest`, but this clearly is not the case.

I'm running `sbt test` to execute the tests, and the output is

```
error: not found: value custom
testListeners += new custom.framework.MyTest
```

I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. 
Does anyone know how this is done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out why stating the package did not work, but moving the `MyTest.scala` file out to the `project` directory, and removing the `custom.framework`package made it work.